# How can I intercept this approximation error in my matlab script?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, approximation

I am trying to find the minimum of a function using this algorithm.
It's not an optimal algorithm, but I don't care at the moment.

Also, you don't have to know how the algorithm works in order to reply, but if you're curious, I talk about it at the end of this post. It's really not that difficult.

**Incriminated Algorithm**

```
function result = fmin(f,a,b,max_error)
if abs(b-a) < max_error
    result = (a+b)/2;
else
    r1 = a+(b-a)*rand(1,1); r2 = a+(b-a)*rand(1,1);
    c = min([r1,r2]); d = max([r1,r2]);
    fc = f(c); fd = f(d);  
    if fc <= fd
        b = d;
    else
        a = c;
    end
    result = fmin(f,a,b,max_error);
end
```

Now, the problem is this algorithm returns a minimum that is far from the actual minimum (computed via the matlab predefined function `fminbnd`) for more than `max_error`, if I use it with values of `max_error <= 1e-10`. This situation, form a theoretical standpoint is not possible.

Being recursive, the algorithm would never return if the condition  `abs(b-a) < max_error` is never satisfied.

So, I think there is some error arising form the approximation of the numbers. At first, I thought that `r1` or `r2` where not computed properly. At some point, the two numbers would go out of the `[a,b]` interval, thus invalidating the hypothesis on which the algorithm is working.

To prove this, I modified the algorithm above to include a check on the interval that's computed at every iteration:

**Incriminated Algorithm 2 [Check on the extremes]**

```
function result = fmin(f,a,b,max_error)
if abs(b-a) < max_error
    result = (a+b)/2;
else
    r1 = a+(b-a)*rand(1,1); r2 = a+(b-a)*rand(1,1);
    c = min([r1,r2]); d=max([r1,r2]);
    % check that c and d are actually inside [a,b]
    if ((c < a)||(d > b))
        disp('Max precision reached');
        result = (a+b)/2;
        return;
    end
    fc = f(c); fd = f(d);  
    if fc <= fd
        b = d;
    else
        a = c;
    end
    result = fmin(f,a,b,max_error);
end
```

But I don't get any additional output from the console.

So, I am thinking there is some error in the computation of `f(c)` or `f(d)`, but I don't know how to prove it.

**Question**

Finally, my questions are

1. Do we, at this point, can be sure that the error is committed in the computation of either one of `f(c)` or `f(d)`?
2. Can we prove it with some line of code? Or better, can we write the algorithm so that it returns when it is supposed to?

**How the algorithm works (not strictly inherent to the question)**

It's an iterative algorithm. Basically, the idea is to generate a sequence of intervals containing the solution, starting from an initial interval [a,b] in which a given function `f` is unimodal.
At every step, we randomly choose two number `c` and `d` so that `a <= c <= d <= b`. Now, if we find that `f(c) > f(d)` it means we are sure that we can discard the values the function assumes before `c` as valid candidates for a minimum, because of the unimodality. So we restrict the interval and repeat the procedure in the interval `[c,b]`. On the contrary, if it's `f(c) < f(d)`, we can discard the values from `d` to `b`, so we repeat the procedure in the interval `[a,d]`.

At every iteration, the interval gets shorter. When its length is minor than the specified `max_error` value, the algorithm returns the medium point of the last interval as an approximation of the minimum value.

---

**EDIT**

I see there is one person that wants to close this question because it is too broad.
Please sir, can you elaborate in the comments?

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoint and stepping through the code?

Comment: Can you give an example `f` for which this algorithm fails? I used `f = @(x) x^2`, and to my surprise, it works. Of course, that is an easy example that does not have any local minima.

Comment: @MartinJ.H. The problem is I don't have a strategy to go for when inspecting via breakpoints. I would check fc and fd at this point, but I couldn't discern good values from bad values in this situation. Regarding the second comment, maybe with `x^2` it fails (gives a value bigger than `error_max`) with a smaller `error_max`. Try 1e-11 or 1e-12 instead... If it still doesn't fail report back, I'll give you my test function asap.

Comment: @MrE I am new to MATLAB, I still don't know how to write those. Also, what tests would you write here? What would you check for?

Answer (score 0):

This subdivision method only works in the special case that your function is (quasi-)convex (one local minimum, monotonically falling on the left, raising on the right). In the case of several local minima it will often converge to one of them, but it is by no means guaranteed that the algorithm finds the global minimum. The reduction from `a` to `c` resp. from `b` to `d` can jump over several local minima.

Comment: The algorithm works. It doesn't work only if the function is convex, it works on a larger hypothesis, called the [unimodality](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodality) hypothesis. Read the last section where I explain the algorithm. It might help.

Comment: Also called quasi-convexity, all level sets are compact (in one dimension single intervals). Still does not invalidate the argument about several minima.

Comment: It does. If a function is unimodal in an interval, or (quasi-)convex , as you say, it can't have more than one minimum in that interval.

Comment: I did not say that. You have unimodal functions where the algorithm works, apart from possible floating point evaluation problems, and more oscillating functions where it is a random event to get to the global minimum. -- To answer your original question, you still need to, as demanded several times, provide the functions and intervals that gave you the wrong results. The algorithm stalling at a non-minimum could also be a floating-point issue.